# Exception : The binary operator AndAlso is not defined for the types 'System.Boolean

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using Lamda expressing to combine condition for Where clause in enity framework
This is my code :
The binary operator AndAlso is not defined for the types 'System.Boolean

```cs
private Expression<Func<Transaction, bool>> BuildFilter(MovementFilterModel filterModel)
{
    Expression<Func<Transaction, bool>> expr = c => true;
    if (filterModel.BankAccounts.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var bank in filterModel.BankAccounts)
        {
            Expression<Func<Transaction, bool>> newPred = c => c.BankAccountId == Guid.Parse(bank);
            expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Transaction, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(expr, newPred), expr.Parameters);
        }
    }
    if (filterModel.Type == Enum.MovementType.EXPENSES)
    {
        Expression<Func<Transaction, bool>> newPred = c => c.Amount < 0;
        expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Transaction, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(expr.Body, newPred), expr.Parameters);
    }
    else if (filterModel.Type == Enum.MovementType.INCOME)
    {
        Expression<Func<Transaction, bool>> newPred = c => c.Amount >= 0;
        expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Transaction, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(expr, newPred), expr.Parameters);
    }
    if (filterModel.StartDate != null)
    {
        Expression<Func<Transaction, bool>> newPred = c => c.MadeOn >= filterModel.StartDate;
        expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Transaction, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(expr, newPred), expr.Parameters);
    }
    if (filterModel.EndDate != null)
    {
        Expression<Func<Transaction, bool>> newPred = c => c.MadeOn <= filterModel.EndDate;
        expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Transaction, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(expr, newPred), expr.Parameters);
    }
    if (filterModel.Category.Subcategories.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var subc in filterModel.Category.Subcategories)
        {
            Expression<Func<Transaction, bool>> newPred = c => c.SubCategoryId == Guid.Parse(subc);
            expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Transaction, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(expr, newPred), expr.Parameters);
        }
    }
    return expr;
}
```

When i call the function i get the exception :
The binary operator AndAlso is not defined for the types 'System.Boolean.
Any Solution please

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: In this line :
 expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Transaction, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(expr.Body, newPred), expr.Parameters);

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing from this:

```cs
expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Transaction, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(expr.Body, newPred), expr.Parameters);
```

To this:

```cs
expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Transaction, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(expr, newPred), expr.Parameters);
```

(Change `expr.Body` to `expr`)

Comment: I tried it without Body before and i have got the same result with the same exception , i think the problem is in the definition of AndAlso not on it's arguments

Comment: I switched to [linq predicate](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) builder which works fine.